# Automatic e-mail account configuration in Thunderbird 2

Tags: email, thunderbird

I'm trying to automatically configure Thunderbird e-mail accounts that are in my domain and its subdomains (eg. user1@my.example.com, user2@sub1.my.example.com). E-mail client doesn't have access to the internet and because of necessary add-on I have to use Thunderbird 2.0.0.6.

Below are my configuration files:
1. rdf (based on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Thunderbird/Thunderbird_ISP_hooks) - adds account type to choose in the account setup but only for one domain
2. xml (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration) - doesn't work (as it probably should - it's advertised to be included in Thunderbird 3 and newer)

My questions:
- is there a way to define subdomains in .rdf file
- is it possible to make xml autoconfiguration work with Thunderbird 2

---

This is example rdf::

```
  <RDF:Description about="NC:ispinfo">
    <NC:providers>
      <NC:nsIMsgAccount about="domain:my.example.com">

        <NC:incomingServer>
          <NC:nsIMsgIncomingServer>
            <NC:hostName>mail.example.com</NC:hostName>

            <NC:type>imap</NC:type>
            <NC:ServerType-imap>
                <NC:nsIImapIncomingServer>
                    <NC:cleanupInboxOnExit>true</NC:cleanupInboxOnExit>
                </NC:nsIImapIncomingServer>
            </NC:ServerType-imap>
            <NC:loginAtStartUp>true</NC:loginAtStartUp>
            <NC:downloadOnBiff>true</NC:downloadOnBiff>
            <NC:rememberPassword>false</NC:rememberPassword>
            <NC:port>993</NC:port>
            <NC:socketType>3</NC:socketType>
          </NC:nsIMsgIncomingServer>
        </NC:incomingServer>

        <NC:smtp>
          <NC:nsISmtpServer>
            <NC:hostname>mail.example.com</NC:hostname>
            <NC:port>465</NC:port>
            <NC:trySSL>2</NC:trySSL>
            <NC:description>MyMail</NC:description>
          </NC:nsISmtpServer>
        </NC:smtp>
        <NC:smtpRequiresUsername>true</NC:smtpRequiresUsername>
        <NC:smtpCreateNewServer>true</NC:smtpCreateNewServer>
        <NC:smtpUsePreferredServer>true</NC:smtpUsePreferredServer>

        <NC:identity>
          <NC:nsIMsgIdentity>
          </NC:nsIMsgIdentity>
        </NC:identity>

        <NC:wizardSkipPanels>true</NC:wizardSkipPanels>
        <NC:wizardShortName>MyMail</NC:wizardShortName>
        <NC:wizardLongName>MyMailExample</NC:wizardLongName>
        <NC:wizardShow>true</NC:wizardShow>
        <NC:wizardPromote>true</NC:wizardPromote>
        <NC:emailProviderName>MyMail</NC:emailProviderName>
        <NC:showServerDetailsOnWizardSummary>true</NC:showServerDetailsOnWizardSummary>
      </NC:nsIMsgAccount>
    </NC:providers>
  </RDF:Description>
</RDF:RDF>
```

And this is my xml:

```
      <domain>my.example.com</domain>
      <domain>sub1.my.example.com</domain>
      <domain>sub2.my.example.com</domain>

      <displayName>MyMailExample</displayName>
      <displayShortName>MyMail</displayShortName>

      <incomingServer type="imap">
         <hostname>mail.example.com</hostname>
         <port>993</port>
         <socketType>SSL</socketType>
         <username>%EMAILADDRESS%</username>
         <authentication>password-cleartext</authentication>
      </incomingServer>

      <outgoingServer type="smtp">
         <hostname>mail.example.com</hostname>
         <port>465</port>
         <socketType>SSL</socketType>
         <username>%EMAILADDRESS%</username>
         <authentication>password-cleartext</authentication>
      </outgoingServer>

    </emailProvider>
</clientConfig>
```

Comment: Before all this, have you looked into porting the extension to a more recent Thunderbird version?

Comment: @grawity It's proprietary extension - I can't mess with it and there is no budget for upgrade to newer version.